# Current-Voltage curve of Light emitting diode

Tags: led, diodes, current-measurement

Under Real time Applications of LED, I am getting negative current in forward voltage(mili volts)...Please tell me what is the reason behind this and how can i avoid it from getting negative current.

Comment: We need to know more about the conditions you measure this under and how. In my reality it is quite hard to get current flow against applied voltage direction.

Comment: I am using Red lED interfaced with Source-monitor unit(SMU) and compter(to measure i/v curve).LED having a very small area (size say cent coin size)..i input my source voltage values in SMU like oltage 0.1v-2.5v,current limiting for 700mA. measurement conditions are having long integration time with delay time of 2s or 200s for each steps(total 41 steps).When i start measuring i am getting negative current at 0.1v.i dont understand why.After some voltage like 0.6V current becomes positive.

Comment: Turn off the lights and see if your negative current goes away.

Comment: i have covered my lED with big box to prevent light entering from outside.

Comment: Replace the LED with a resistor. Do you still get that sort of behaviour? If so, suspect an offset in your current measurement.

Comment: yes i did replace it with resistor and i still get same behaviour. off set current of my measurement instrument is in micro Amp.its a precision SMU.

Comment: -1 for not improving your question after being given specific suggestions how to do so. Also please provide a schematic of your measurement setup.